# Purge command greyed out in exchange system manager

Tags: exchange-2003, email-server

Today I wanted to delete one of our mailboxes, so first in the AD I deleted the user's mailbox. Then when I try to purge the mailbox in ESM something goes wrong because the Purge and Reconnect options are inactive / grayed out.

Any idea what I should do now?

(I need to add the user which was previously removed, but now there are two mailboxes included in ESM)

Comment: Has the mailbox maintenance process run? What is the retention setting for deleted mailboxes?

Comment: Sorry but how can i check this? (The language of my Exchange is diferent than english, and i can't figure out what you ask..)

Comment: On ESM - Server properties --> Mailbox management process set to Never Run if you ask this..

Comment: Deletion setting is: Keep deleted mailboxes for 30 day. 
But earlier this funciont (Purge) was not greyed out...i don't know what happend. We made offline defrag, if its matter..

Answer (score 2):

What you were seeing is described [in this article from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998119(EXCHG.65).aspx). The gist is as follows:

- Mailboxes are not marked as deleted in the Information Store database immediately when you delete them using management tools.
- The next time the Mailbox Management or Store Maintenance process runs the mailbox will be marked as deleted. If it has been deleted for the duration of the "Keep Deleted Mailboxes" setting then it will be purged automatically.
- After the mailbox has been marked as deleted it is able to be purged in the Exchange System Manager.